# How to implement different value for Multiple instances of same webpart in subsites?

Tags: instance, multiple-instances, web-parts

I create a webpart, for which values are provided dynamically through the toolpart. I get the proper output. But the problem is when i add a new instance of the same webpart in a subsite, It takes the value from the other tool part,

In simple words, The value in the toolpart remain same for all the instances of the same webpart. I need to handle different value for each instance of the webpart.

Can any of you have a better solution for this problem.